# ESLint Parsing Error when importing a typescript file

Tags: typescript, electron, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am developing an electron application that uses typescript and I'm trying to setup ESLint. Almost everything seems to work fine except one -very strange- issue. Let's assume we have the following structure:

```
.
├── electron/
│   └── main/
│       ├── index.ts
│       └── test.ts
├── .eslintrc.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.node.json
```

**electron/main/index.ts**

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, shell } from 'electron';

import { a, b } from './test' // Keep this line in mind

[...]
```

**electron/main/test.ts**

```
export const a = "a"

export const b = "b"
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "electron/**/*"],
  "references": [
    { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.node.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "package.json", "electron"]
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"],
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended", 
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "dist-electron/",
    ".output/",
    "dist/",
    "public/",
    "**/*.min.js",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "**/*.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

When ESLint is trying to lint the "test.js" file, then it fails with the following error:

```
$ npx eslint ./electron/main/test.ts

C:\project\electron\main\test.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/electron\main\test.ts` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting##i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file
```

However, the weird thing is that if I remove the import from main.ts file then the file is parsed and linted without errors. The same is also true if I'm making the import along with the extension (`import { a, b } from './test.ts'`) as well as if I use require instead of import (`const a = require('./test.ts')`)

I also tried to use the plugins `eslint-plugin-import` and `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` along with the suggested config, but same result when the `test.ts` file is imported into another file.

*relevant part when eslint is ran with the --debug flag*

```
eslintrc:ignore-pattern Check {
  filePath: 'C:\\project\\electron\\main\\test.ts',
  dot: false,
  relativePath: 'electron/main/test.ts',
  result: false
} +2ms
  eslint:cli-engine Lint C:\project\electron\main\test.ts +0ms
  eslint:linter Linting code for C:\project\electron\main\test.ts (pass 1) +0ms
  eslint:linter Verify +0ms
  eslint:linter With ConfigArray: C:\project\electron\main\test.ts +0ms
  eslint:linter Parsing: C:\project\electron\main\test.ts +2ms
  eslint:linter Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/electron\main\test.ts` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting##i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file
  eslint:linter Error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/electron\main\test.ts` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting##i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file
    at createProjectProgram (C:\project\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\create-program\createProjectProgram.js:104:11)
    at getProgramAndAST (C:\project\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\parser.js:36:89)
    at parseAndGenerateServices (C:\project\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\parser.js:140:11)
    at Object.parseForESLint (C:\project\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\parser\dist\parser.js:90:80)
    at parse (C:\project\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js:806:22)
    at Linter._verifyWithoutProcessors (C:\project\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js:1349:33)
    at Linter._verifyWithConfigArray (C:\project\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js:1769:21)
    at Linter.verify (C:\project\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js:1476:65)
    at Linter.verifyAndFix (C:\project\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter\linter.js:2028:29)
    at verifyText (C:\project\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:245:48) +912ms
  eslint:linter Generating fixed text for C:\project\electron\main\test.ts (pass 1) +2ms
  eslint-code-fixer Applying fixes +0ms
  eslint-code-fixer shouldFix parameter was false, not attempting fixes +0ms
  eslint:file-enumerator Complete iterating files: ["./electron/main/test.ts"] +2s
  eslint:cli-engine Linting complete in: 1630ms +918ms
```

Comment: Can you also share `tsconfig.node.json` file? It appears that `test.ts` file is getting ignored in some `tsconfig` file.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I included the `tsconfig.node.json` in the original post and I think you're right! When I remove `electron` from the `includes` of `tsconfig.node.json` then `test.ts` is parsed. My `src` folder is basically the renderer process which is a Vue application (I have not configured ESLint for Vue yet). This `tsconfig.node.json` comes from [this](https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-vue) template I'm using. I'm not sure why I've added `package.json` and `electron` in the includes. Is there a better way to specify the configs for typescript?